# Can Terminal access the microphone in Catalina? (for SoX, FFmpeg, Ecasound, pyaudio etc.)

Tags: terminal, audio, catalina, permission, microphone

When I try to record audio from the command line with programs such as SoX or FFmpeg it doesn't record anything and ends up with a flat-line recording. I am guessing this is due to privacy restrictions from macOS Mojave/Catalina. This is similar to the issue Audacity is having, in which the fix is opening it from the terminal to trigger a request for microphone permissions.

[This answer suggests granting Terminal access](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/347775/375240) to the microphone from System Preferences. However, it will only show up in the list if Terminal requests it. So is there a way to grant an application unrequested permissions?

I also saw that [Apple tech support have said non-GUI apps can't access the mic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58275130/9486946). Does this mean command line audio recording is completely broken? As it seemed to work perfectly on previous versions, could there be a fix for it like there is for Audacity?

Comment: I don’t know (yet) a way of preemptively adding devices/applications accessibility permissions.  However, as for the the “Apple tech support answer...”. They are completely wrong:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326390/119271

Comment: Thanks, I have found a way to trigger the mic request for Terminal now! It is the exact same solution as the Audacity fix on Catalina - I just didn't think it would work for me because the Audacity fix didn't even work for me for some reason.

Comment: Post it as an answer!  I’ll upvote so you can get the credit for the work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Terminal isn't showing up in the System Preferences list for microphone permissions, open it by:

```
open /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
```

Then run a program that uses the mic e.g.

```
sox -d -d
```

(Note, sox is not pre-installed.) This will let you hear your mic input.

That should trigger it to request. If that didn't work try running the command on a different command line e.g. iTerm2. This is a problem and solution similar to the one for Audacity on Catalina. I'm not sure what the exact cause is though.

Comment: Nice!  Glad you got it working! +1

Comment: Thanks! I’m a new user here and I’ve been seeing you around a lot, you’re a legend!